# Sorting does not work with dynamic column

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have one generic function like:

```
public TabMasterListViewModel GetTabMasterList(string OrderByColumn, string OrderType, int PageSize, int CurrentPage)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((CurrentPage == 0) || (PageSize == 0))
                    return null;

                IQueryable<TabMaster> query = _tabmasterRepository.GetQueryable();
                TabMasterListViewModel model = new TabMasterListViewModel();
                model.TotalItemCount = query.Count();
                if (model.TotalItemCount == 0)
                    return null;
                model.TotalPageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)model.TotalItemCount / (double)PageSize);
                if (model.TotalPageCount != 1)
                {
                    if (OrderType.ToUpper() == "ASC")
                        query = query.OrderBy(x => x.colID).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
                    else
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.colID).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
                }
                model.ThisPageItemCount = query.Count();
                model.TabMasterList = new List<TabMasterViewModel>();
                AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<TabMaster, TabMasterViewModel>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.colID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.colID));
                model.TabMasterList = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(query.ToList(), model.TabMasterList);

                return model;
            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                this.LogError("Error getting the TabMaster list", e);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

if i am use following line

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => x.colID).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

then sorting is complete working as aspect.

if i am using **OrderByColumn** in following line, then sorting dose not work.

```
 if (OrderType.ToUpper() == "ASC")
                        query = query.OrderBy(x => OrderByColumn).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
                    else
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => OrderByColumn).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```

Please suggest what i am missing?
Thanks,

Comment: You are right, because this solution is not mine, i found it over the internet and **i mentioned URL and Author as well**.

Comment: Now all we have to worry about is link rot...  Ah, internets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the Excellent solution for the same

http://landman-code.blogspot.com/2008/11/linq-to-entities-string-based-dynamic.html

Thanks a lot **Davy Landman** for excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may try [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx). It's more adapted to the kind of dynamic queries that you are trying to implement.

Comment: @imdadhusen, well, if this doesn't work for you (no idea why it wouldn't) prepare yourself for `if (OrderByColumn == "Foo") { query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Foo)... } else if (OrderByColumn == "Bar") { query = query.OrderBy(x => x.Bar)... } else if ...`. I think you get the point and the horror you will end up with if you have many of them :-). LINQ extension methods operate on static lambdas where properties need to be known at compile-time. That's why people wrote Dynamic LINQ => in order to address those issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reflection to get `OrderByColumn` dynamically:

```
query = query.OrderBy(x => typeof(x).GetProperty(OrderByColumn)).Skip((CurrentPage - 1) * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
```